# how to retrieve volume from a removed Docker container?

Tags: docker

If I have a data volume container, and I stop & remove the container (without the -v flag which would remove the volume), is it still possible to start a new data volume container with the *orphaned* volume? Or is the data lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you remove a container with `docker rm` but without the `-v` flag, your data will still be available inside the `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/<your-volume-id>/` directory on the host.

To use the orphaned volume in a new docker container, you can either mount that directory from the host or attach a new empty volume to your docker container & then sync the data.

Comment: yeah that was what I was thinking too, I was hoping there was a more non-workaround like solution, but this'll do

Comment: Have you ever since recovered the data?