# Docker undo rm container

Tags: docker

I accidentally removed my container with "docker rm [CONTAINER_ID]".

Is there anyway that I can undo this, or restore the data in the container?

It was a CentOS image.

```
$docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 30
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:16-1179651-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem:
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 8.998 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 43.66 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 11.45 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.136 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /srv/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /srv/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.862 GiB
Name: ip-172-31-14-126
ID: QXWS:5VBE:CIZV:NF57:KNTZ:ZOIV:HIZZ:PXKW:44LT:KVFZ:ECQI:FPIX
Username: hogehoge
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

> Similar question:
>   [how to retrieve volume from a removed Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009619/how-to-retrieve-volume-from-a-removed-docker-container)
>
> The above question is asking how to retrieve data from a "data volume
>   container", but my one was not. I stored everything inside the CentOS
>   image.

Comment: @JK Please tell me a right place to ask this. You can try to search "docker" to see if any of them are coding question.

Comment: Looks like a good fit for http://serverfault.com/ ([source](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8667/what-is-the-scope-of-what-docker-questions-are-on-topic-here?cb=1))

Comment: @JK. This is a good place to ask this question. Stack Overflow isn't only for coding questions. It is also for questions about tools that programmers use, like docker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to retrieve volume from a removed Docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009619/how-to-retrieve-volume-from-a-removed-docker-container)

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks. I have read that question before I asked mine. His container is a "data volume container", but my one is not. But I'm still not sure... I'm kind of lost.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, getting data from a volume is totally different than from a container.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is probably no.

According to the comment I received from docker forum:

> docker rm is just like rm on the host, there is no going back

Personal story:
I lost 3 weeks of my business data, and having big trouble with it.
Good lesson to teach myself that never "rm" unless you are 100% sure what you are doing, and backup your data!

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I hope I didn't get your hopes up with the dupellicate comment I posted.

Comment: @Paulro What doesn't kill me makes me stronger ;)

Comment: Pro tip : beware of reduced alertness !  I used `docker attach`, logged out & in, and used up arrow to redo `docker attach` several times, but at some point I got a different bash history with `docker rm` instead… TT