# How to restore a mongo Docker container on the Mac

Tags: macos, mongodb, docker, osx-elcapitan

I removed my mongo container

```
docker rm myMongoDB
```

Did I lose all my data, or I can restore it? If so, how?

When I try to run another container from the image

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d mongo --name myMongo2
```

it won't run and its STATUS says `Exited (2) 8 seconds ago`.

Comment: If your container use `volume`, likely the data are still available on your machine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009619/how-to-retrieve-volume-from-a-removed-docker-container. Backup the folder before you do anything in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: @warmoverflow I had seen that stackoverflow entry  but I don' have a `/var/lib/docker` directory. Not sure if it is because I upgraded to El Capitan since I used my mongodb last time, or because it is a Mac, not Linux.

Comment: @thaJeztah provided a good answer. Adding on that, since you are using Mac OS X, you are using Docker Toolbox. The `/var/lib/docker` folder is inside the docker toolbox vm, which you can login using `docker-machine ssh default`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official `mongo` image on Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) defines two volumes to store data [in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/191cc63288fb44c2fd147eac27ade07ae4b6b0b5/3.2/Dockerfile#L60). If you did not explicitly specify a `-v` / `--volume` option when running the container, Docker created anonymous (unnamed) volumes for those, and those volumes may still be around. It may be a bit difficult to find which volumes were last used by the container, because they don't have a name.

To list all volumes that are still present on the docker host, use;

```
docker volume ls
```

Which should give you something like this;

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               9142c58ad5ac6d6e40ccd84096605f5393bf44ab7b5fe51edfa23cd1f8e13e4b
local               4ac8e34c11ac7955b9b79af10c113b870edd0869889d1005ee17e98e7c6c05f1
local               da0b4a7a00c4b60c492599dabe1dbc501113ae4b2dd1811527384a5dc26cab13
local               81a40483ae00d72dcfa2117b3ae40f3fe79038544253e60b85a8d0efc8f3d139
```

To see what's in a volume, you can attach it to a temporary container, and check what's in there. For example;

```
docker run -it -v 81a40483ae00d72dcfa2117b3ae40f3fe79038544253e60b85a8d0efc8f3d139:/volume-data ubuntu
```

That will start an interactive shell in a new ubuntu container, with the volume `81a40483ae00d72dcfa2117b3ae40f3fe79038544253e60b85a8d0efc8f3d139` mounted at `/volume-data/` inside the container.

You can then go into that directory, and check if it's the volume you're looking for:

```
root@08c11a34ed44:/# cd /volume-data/
root@08c11a34ed44:/volume-data# ls -la
```

once you identified which volumes (according to the Dockerfile, the mongo image uses two), you can start a new mongo container, and mount those volumes;

```
docker run -d --name mymongo \
  -v 4ac8e34c11ac7955b9b79af10c113b870edd0869889d1005ee17e98e7c6c05f1:/data/db/ \
  -v  da0b4a7a00c4b60c492599dabe1dbc501113ae4b2dd1811527384a5dc26cab13:/data/configdb/ \
  mongo
```

I really suggest you read the [Where to Store Data](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) section in the documentation for the mongo image on Docker Hub to prevent loosing your data.

**NOTE**

I also noted that your last command puts the `--name myMongo2` *after* the image name; it should be *before* `mongo` (the image name). Also `myMongo2` is an invalid container name, as it is not allowed to have uppercase characters.

Comment: Apparently, the "Where to Store Data" section has a WARNING for OS X and it says that it is not possible to run a MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host. Good to know! Anyway, my data should be in the `/data/...` directory(-ies) for now. However, I don't have a `/data/` directory. It may be that when I upgraded OS X to El Capitan recently, it got wiped out??

Comment: Also, I don't have a `docker volume ls` command on my Docker. `docker: 'volume' is not a docker command.` I am on Docker 1.8.1, in case `volume` is new command.

Comment: Looks like you're running an older version of Docker then; latest versions of docker toolbox can be found on https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases. You may be interested in https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/, which resolves many issues with mapping host directories

Comment: I upgraded docker to 1.10.3, so I have `docker volume ls` now. Just to confirm, when I mount the volumes as you describe, I should see in the `/volume-data/` inside the container the `/data/db/` and `/data/configdb` directories? Or how do I know I found the right volumes?

Comment: The other contains:
Checked all 34 volumes. Only 2 has data in the /volume-data/ directory. One contains:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 999 999 4.0K Aug 22  2015 _tmp,
drwxr-xr-x 2 999 999 4.0K Aug 22  2015 journal,
-rw------- 1 999 999  64M Aug 22  2015 local.0,
-rw------- 1 999 999  16M Aug 22  2015 local.ns,
-rwxr-xr-x 1 999 999    0 Aug 22  2015 mongo.lock,
-rw-r--r-- 1 999 999   69 Aug 22  2015 storage.bson`

Comment: The other one contains:
`-rw------- 1 999 999  64M Oct 28 02:10 admin.0,
-rw------- 1 999 999  16M Oct 28 02:10 admin.ns,
drwxr-xr-x 2 999 999 4.0K Feb  4 18:03 journal,
-rw------- 1 999 999  64M Feb  4 18:03 local.0,
-rw------- 1 999 999  16M Feb  4 18:03 local.ns,
-rw------- 1 999 999  64M Feb  4 18:03 meteor.0,
-rw------- 1 999 999 128M Dec  8 20:39 meteor.1,
-rw------- 1 999 999 256M Dec  8 20:39 meteor.2`

Comment: ... cont'd 
`-rw------- 1 999 999 512M Oct 21 23:45 meteor.3
-rw------- 1 999 999 1.0G Feb  4 18:03 meteor.4
-rw------- 1 999 999  16M Jan 27 21:58 meteor.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 999 999    2 Feb  4 18:03 mongod.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 999 999   69 Aug 22  2015 storage.bson
-rw------- 1 999 999  64M Sep 26  2015 test.0
-rw------- 1 999 999  16M Sep 26  2015 test.ns`.
A MeteorJS app uses the mongo db.

Comment: You won't see the `/data/db/` and `/data/configdb` directories inside the volumes; the volumes are mounted at that location inside the container, so all the files written to the `/data/db/` and `/data/configdb` directories will be located at the root (`/`) of the volume, so directly in `/volume-data/` if you mount them there. As mentioned; finding the right volume will be tricky, possibly the last changed/modified dates of the files could help you, but other than that, it's probably just having luck (especially if you have a lot of volumes still around)

Comment: Ok. It was kinda tedious, but worked. Out of 34 images 2 contained data in the `/volume-data/` directory and I just guessed which one is which (db or configdb) in your answer.

Comment: Great to hear! It was a long shot, but glad it worked out :-)