# Reattaching orphaned docker volumes

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using a docker volume, specified in my dockerfile so that my data can persist on the host.  The dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM base-image
VOLUME /path/to/something
RUN do_stuff
....
```

When I run the container it creates a volume (call it *VolumeA*) which I can see when I do a `docker volume ls`.

If I stop and remove the container, the *VolumeA* sticks around as expected.

My question is, if I run a new version of the container, is there a way to use *VolumeA* rather than have it create a new one?

Comment: That's why you should have named volumes

Comment: So the purpose of VOLUME in a dockerfile is purely to persist data after the container that created it is removed?  There's no way to re-use that data in another container?

Comment: You can but it is just not straightforward as named volume. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009619/how-to-retrieve-volume-from-a-removed-docker-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using named volumes, as you can mount them easily to a new container.

But for unnamed volume, I:

- run my container (the VOLUME directive causes it to create a new volume to a new path that you can get by inspecting it)
- move the path of the old volume to that new path.

Before [docker volume commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume), [I used to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34775351/6309) with [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164156/6309): [`updateDataContainerPath.sh`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/912b988add3e532c3d073767fc66c2f5759df152/updateDataContainerPath).

But again, these days, none of my images have a `VOLUME` in them: I create separately named volumes ([`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)), and mount them to containers at runtime (`docker run -v my-named-volume:/my/path`)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Have removed the VOLUME from my dockerfile and manage it now with a -v at runtime.   Much nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `-v` flag in the `docker run` command to bind the existing volume to your new docker container

`docker run -v VolumeA:/path/to/something [image]`

Also look into the `--volumes-from` flag to mount volumes used or created by other containers.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/