# Docker volume: backup

Tags: docker, backup, tar

I have created a volume container. And a container which mounts to en from the volume container.

Volume container:

```
docker run -d --name nexus-data nexus:1.0 echo "data-only container for Nexus"
```

My Nexus container:

```
docker run -d -p 8443:8443 -p 8081:8081  --name nexus --restart=always --volumes-from nexus-data nexus:1.0
```

So this is working fine. I'm able to delete and recreate my nexus-container without losing data. The volume container (which isn't in running state) is saving the data.

But the bottleneck of this approach is the volume-container. When I accidentally delete this container, all the data is gone.
This can happen pretty fast because some useful commands which will delete stopped containers will also delete the volume containers.

So I want to create backups for my volume-containers. 
I tried to ways:

```
$ docker cp nexus:/this/folder/ /home/ubuntu/backup-folder
```

And

```
$ docker import nexus > /home/ubuntu/backup.tar
```

So I have one folder and one .tar in my home directory.
Now I want to know what's the right approach to import one of these backups?

*I read about the `docker export` command to create a 'new image' but I don't like this approach because my backup folder is pretty big.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't use data volume container: since docker 1.9, you can use [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) instead. Docker now has [volume commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume).

> The following example also creates the `my-named-volume` volume, this time using the `docker volume create` command.

```
$ docker volume create --name my-named-volume -o size=20GB
$ docker run -d -P \
  -v my-named-volume:/opt/webapp \
  --name web training/webapp python app.py
```

Those volumes are named, listed by docker volume ls, and you can backup `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

With data volume container, you would need to memorize the path of the data within that container (`docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 0).Source }}`), write it to a file, and use that path when you create a new data volume container.
I used to do that with [`updateDataContainerPath.sh`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/912b988add3e532c3d073767fc66c2f5759df152/updateDataContainerPath). See "[Reattaching orphaned docker volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203287/6309)".

I do not need that convoluted mechanism since docker 1.9 and named volumes.

Comment: I have to install the flocker plugin for this?

Comment: @MaxC No, this is in docker by default.

Comment: I got: Error response from daemon: create my-jenkins-volume: create my-jenkins-volume: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: plugin not found after trying to create such a volume (I'm using a real docker, not machine, on ubuntu 14.04, version of docker is 1.11.1

Comment: @MaxC What happend if you do not use the `-d flocker`? I have edited the answer to remove the reference to that plugin.

Comment: thanks. than it works. did some small testing and the data of my container persists. Very cool. I can even 'cd' into the /var/lib/docker/volume/myvolume! I still have my data in the old way. Can I just perform a docker cp on 'old' container to my local machine and than past the folder in my /var/lib/docker/my-volume?

Comment: + can you just 'scp' that /var/lib/docker/volume to other servers and use it with other containers?

Comment: No, the idea is to mount an existing volume to other containers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113057/discussion-between-maxc-and-vonc).

Comment: @MaxC back at work (no chat). You can use your backup by creating a new empty volume, and copying your data into `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<my_new_volume>`

Comment: So just a docker copy of my existing a folder inside my existing container and paste in the the folder of my new volume (created by docker volume create ...)

Comment: @MaxC no, I would only backup what is recorded in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<avolume>`.

Comment: so a copy of whats inside /var/lib/docker/volumes/a37dfd3/_data (old volume) to my new /var/lib/docker/volumes/my-new-volume/_data

Comment: @MaxC Yes, in term of backup, that is what I would copy/restore.

Comment: Isn't it going to complain about my user? because it's user jenkins or nexus but this user doesn't exist on my host. and I'm only able to copy as root (otherwise I cannot access /var/lib/docker/volumes)

Comment: @MaxC if you backup using tar (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR, http://superuser.com/a/838399/141), it will backup the tree with the relevant user and permissions.