# Volume sharing in Docker and Virtualbox

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, kitematic

I have installed docker toolbox on my Windows PC,when i install containers on it using Kitematic, I want to share a folder with my local machine. However docker runs in virtualbox on the default machine in VirtualBox.

So, i guess i first have to do a fvolume share of the virtualbox vm with my local machine and then a second share of the docker container with the folder that I shared in virtualbox. Could someone assist me in this please?

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't need to share any more folder: docker-machine will create a VM which auto-mount `C:\Users\<yourLogin>`.

```
docker-machine ls
docker-machine ssh default
cd /C/Users/<yourLogin>
```

You can [mount other folders from your hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608266/6309), but you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But when specifying the folder path for containers like mysql or mongodb should we just point to the /C/Users/<myLogin> path?

Comment: @ArjunSehgal No, you don't specify any path, you create named volume (with docker 1.9+) with `docker volume create` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37462890/6309): https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume

Comment: @ArjunSehgal I explain it (for mongodb) at the *end* of my older answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35402611/6309

Answer (score 0):

I'm running docker version **18.03.0 ce** on Windows 10, and the C:\Users folder is shared as **/c-users** on the docker VM (default), so using the command line

`docker run -it -v /c-users/my_windows_user/project:/media/project ubuntu:16.04 bash`

I can access the Windows project files from **/media/project** within the Ubuntu container